# JQuery simple slider issue on timeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I have a function called `slideMe()` and I need to launch that with delay of some seconds for each slider links.

jquery version is 1.4.2

code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var img_id;
    var clicked;

 function slideMe(img_id){

       $('.slider-menu-item').css('color','#fff');
       $('#'+img_id).css('color','#EBE1B9');
       $('.slider-img').hide();
       $('#slider-img-'+img_id).fadeIn(600);

    };

$.each($('.slider-menu-item'),function(){

   img_id = $(this).attr("id");
   setTimeout("slideMe()",900);

    console.log(img_id)

});
   $('.slider-menu-item').live('click',function(){
       img_id = $(this).attr("id");
       clicked = 1;
    slideMe(img_id);
}); 

});//end document.ready
```

but in console logs I receive error that says:

> slideMe is not defined

How I can do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the `slideMe` function outside of the document.ready handler. Also it would be better to pass directly the method to setTimeout instead of using strings. Also the `slideMe` method expects an argument so make sure you pass it:

```
function slideMe(img_id) {
    $('.slider-menu-item').css('color', '#fff');
    $('#' + img_id).css('color', '#EBE1B9');
    $('.slider-img').hide();
    $('#slider-img-' + img_id).fadeIn(600);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var img_id;
    var clicked;

    $('.slider-menu-item').each(function() {
        img_id = $(this).attr('id');
        setTimeout(function() {
            slideMe(img_id);    
        }, 900);
    });

    $('.slider-menu-item').live('click',function() {
        img_id = $(this).attr("id");
        clicked = 1;
        slideMe(img_id);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: thanks, i tryed out this code and seems ok, BUT as i put console.log(img_id) it shows me always img_id = 5 :/, what should be?  unreal, cause all .slider-menu-item ids are 1,2,3,4,5 :(

Answer (score 0):

try `slideMe=function(){...}` instead of `function slideMe(){...}`